# How to get AWS credentials in Angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-cloudwatch

I am making a small Angular application to view Cloudwatch Logs with the `@aws-sdk/client-cloudwatch-logs` package.

This is currently working to initialize the client:

```
  const config: CloudWatchLogsClientConfig = {
    region: region,
    credentials: {
      accessKeyId: account.accessKeyId,
      secretAccessKey: account.secretAccessKey,
    },
  };

  const client = new CloudWatchLogsClient(config);
```

The above code works fine for my personal account to test things, because I am able to create access keys for this.

But in the account I'll be using this application I don't have access to do it. I authenticate by impersonating a role.

In the .NET SDK I am able to use the credentials stored in the `.aws\credentials` to pass to the SDK, but in the JavaScript SDK I didn't find anything like this.

What would be the best way to do this in Angular?